# Bridge two interfaces with netplan

Tags: networking, ethernet, netplan

I have two physical interfaces in my device: `eth0` and `eth1`

I want to use `eth0` to communicate with a raspberry directly connected via ethernet. The raspberry's static IP is 192.168.1.201.
The `eth1` interface is connected to a normal router (with network `192.168.1.0/24`) for internet access.

My netplan configurations is as follows:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.11/24
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.1.201/32
          via: 0.0.0.0
    eth1:
      dhcp4: yes
      # I normally get assigned 192.168.1.100
```

There seems to be a problem due to the fact that both interfaces are using the same `192.168.1.0/24` network. When I reboot I am unable to get an IP from the dhcp server in `eth1` unless I unplug the raspberry on my `eth0` interface.

Does anyone have some idea on how I could bridge the two interfaces?

**Constraints:**

- Cannot change raspberry's static IP
- Cannot connect raspberry to router, it must be directly plugged in to the `eth0` interface.
- Cannot change router's configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set up a bridge with netplan is documented at https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-configure-network-bridges.

Note that when using a bridge, the IP configuration goes on the bridge and not the component interfaces.